# How to resolve the error in the nested if formula in excel in the following example

Tags: excel

DH8D, DH4, B47, ATR, AT7, 73W,73J ,73H ,788,773, 744,739,738,333,332,320, these are the aircraft types and
78  78  76  70  70  149 170 170 256 380 423 168 180 255 278 180 125 
these are corresponding no. of seats. 
Now when I will enter a type in column I want that the respective no. of seats will automatic generate in the next column, hence I wrote the nested if formula like,

```
=IF(A3=DH8D,"78",IF(A3=DH4,"78",IF(A3=B47,"76",IF(A3=ATR,"70",IF(A3=AT7,"70",IF(A3=73W,"149",IF(A3=73J,"170",IF(A3=73H,"170",IF(A3=788,"256",IF(A3=773,"380",IF(A3=744,"423",IF(A3=739,"168",IF(A3=738,"180",IF(A3=333,"255",IF(A3=332,"278",IF(A3=320,"180"))))))))))))))))
```

But excel always shows an error and displayed the message, "There's a problem with this formula".  What should I do resolve this?

Comment: You have 16 aircraft type and 17 corresponding numbers for seats. ??

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention 319 type..

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft should never have increased the limit for nesting IF functions.

Please, please, don't do this. Just put the aircraft and the seats into two columns and use a lookup formula like this:

=VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$B$18,2,FALSE)

[image]

Just imagine the nested IF formula is in your workbook 100 times and then the ATR is upgraded to 72 seats. With the nested IF formula you will need to update 100 formulas. With the Vlookup you only need to change B5 from 70 to 72.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added quotation marks while testing text values. Eg: A3=ATR is supposed to be A3="ATR"

```
=IF(A3="DH8D","78",IF(A3="DH4","78",IF(A3="B47","76",IF(A3="ATR","70",IF(A3="AT7","70",IF(A3="73W","149",IF(A3="73J","170",IF(A3="73H","170",IF(A3="788","256",IF(A3="773","380",IF(A3="744",423,IF(A3="739","168",IF(A3="738","180",IF(A3="333","255",IF(A3="332","278",IF(A3="320","180"))))))))))))))))
```

However, I would always recommend you to make a separate table for aircraft number and corresponding seats and using one of the lookup formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I got that excel error because I was using , (comma) on conditional formating in  MS-Excel-2016
Instead I replaced all the , with ; everything went well.